# Ansible, autoinstall python dependencies

Tags: python, ansible

I can [share](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#embedding-modules-and-plugins-in-roles) my custom python plugin via library folder directly in role, but how can i specify python dependencies to check and install by ansible? I know i can use requirements.txt or setuptools to install dependencies manually in yaml code, but maybe there is some build in functionality for it in ansible? Just like for roles in `meta/main.yml` for example.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html

Comment: no, there is no "auto-install dependencies". If your module needs additional libs, you need to use pip module to install them before using the module.